# Host and Client sync problem in Godot 4 multiplayer RPG game?

Tags: godot, multiplayer, godot4

This  multiplayer RPG game, which  i make, have a lots of problems :). This time, the problew is that, when the host place down a item with the my grid system, in remote tab(at Editor where you can see what is going on with the nodes when you ran the program) under the PlayerBuildings node nothing appears (in game the item is visible only for host) but when the client build sth is apear in remote tab  but again is visible only for client!!!. Also i get this error

> get_node: Node not found:"World/PlayerBuildings/@Camp1@3/MultiplayerSynchronizer"   process_simplify_path: Condition "node == nullptr" is true.

Have anyone any idea??

[image: Here is my node tree]

And here is my grid base code:

```
extends Node2D

@onready var camp_fire = preload("res://src/Scenes/camp.tscn")
var tile_size =16

enum {OBSTACTLE, COLLECTABLE,RESOURCE}
var grid_size = Vector2(160,160)
var grid = []


func _ready():
    for x in range(grid_size.x):
        grid.append([])
        for y in range(grid_size.y):
            grid[x].append(null)
    var positions = []
    for i in range (50):
        var xcoor = (randi() % int(grid_size.x))
        var ycoor = (randi() % int(grid_size.y))
        var grid_pos = Vector2(xcoor,ycoor)
        if not grid_pos in positions:
            positions.append(grid_pos)

func _input(event):
    if GameManager.enable:
        if event.is_action_pressed("LeftClick"):
            var mouse_pos = get_global_mouse_position()
            var multiX = int(round(mouse_pos.x)/tile_size)
            var numX = multiX*tile_size
            var multiY = int(round(mouse_pos.y)/tile_size)
            var numY = multiY*tile_size
            var new_pos = Vector2(multiX, multiY)
            var new_camp_fire = camp_fire.instantiate()
            new_camp_fire.name = str(new_camp_fire.name + str(multiplayer.get_unique_id()) )
            new_camp_fire.set_position(tile_size*new_pos)
            grid[multiX][multiY] = OBSTACTLE
            get_tree().root.get_node("World").get_node("PlayerBuildings").add_child(new_camp_fire)
```

Comment: You have posted the code to add a campfire locally, but not the objects/code related to the networking. I would suggest trying to create a minimal code example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I think this is the solution!! I have the script to add the campfire localy not at the networking!!! But how i can add the campfire to networking??? With RPC???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I add a rpc fuction in my script and finaly it is working. The new code is that:

```
extends Node2D

@onready var camp_fire = preload("res://src/Scenes/camp.tscn")
var tile_size =16

enum {OBSTACTLE, COLLECTABLE,RESOURCE}
var grid_size = Vector2(160,160)
var grid = []


func _ready():
    for x in range(grid_size.x):
        grid.append([])
        for y in range(grid_size.y):
            grid[x].append(null)
    var positions = []
    for i in range (50):
        var xcoor = (randi() % int(grid_size.x))
        var ycoor = (randi() % int(grid_size.y))
        var grid_pos = Vector2(xcoor,ycoor)
        if not grid_pos in positions:
            positions.append(grid_pos)

func _input(event):
    if GameManager.enable:
        if event.is_action_pressed("LeftClick"):
            var mouse_pos = get_global_mouse_position()
            var multiX = int(round(mouse_pos.x)/tile_size)
            var numX = multiX*tile_size
            var multiY = int(round(mouse_pos.y)/tile_size)
            var numY = multiY*tile_size
            var new_pos = Vector2(multiX, multiY)
            grid[multiX][multiY] = OBSTACTLE
            rpc("_item_placement",new_pos)
            

@rpc("any_peer","call_local","reliable")
func _item_placement(new_pos):
    var new_camp_fire = camp_fire.instantiate()
    new_camp_fire.name = str(new_camp_fire.name + str(multiplayer.get_unique_id()) )
    new_camp_fire.set_position(tile_size*new_pos)
    get_tree().root.get_node("World").get_node("PlayerBuildings").add_child(new_camp_fire)
```